# AWS dynamodb ScanInput ExpressionAttributeValue not working as expected

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have written a scan query to get the only enabled data like this

```
    const FilterExpression = 'enabled = :enabled';
    const ExpressionAttributeValues = { ':enabled': { 'BOOL': true } };
    const scanParameters: ScanInput = {
      TableName,
      ExclusiveStartKey: cursor ?? undefined,
      Limit: Number(filter.limit) ?? undefined,
      FilterExpression,
      ExpressionAttributeValues,
    };
```

but It won't return any value. When I change the ExpressionAttributeValue to

```
const ExpressionAttributeValues = { ':enabled': true };
```

it returns the value but doesn't satisfy the type of ScanInput. Throws errors like this [image]

"Type '{ ':enabled': boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ExpressionAttributeValueMap'.
Property '':enabled'' is incompatible with the index signature. "
One solution I know is to create a new type and assign value according but why type ScanInput format data is not working when scanning the data?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough of your code to fully understand your issue. My assumption here is that you are mixing up clients, meaning you are defining your parameters for the low level client by using DynamoDB JSON `{ 'BOOL': true }` but you are actually using the Document client which uses native JSON.

```
/*
  Convert the key JavaScript object you are retrieving to the
  required Amazon DynamoDB record. The format of values specifies
  the datatype. The following list demonstrates different
  datatype formatting requirements:
  String: "String",
  NumAttribute: 1,
  BoolAttribute: true,
  ListAttribute: [1, "two", false],
  MapAttribute: { foo: "bar" },
  NullAttribute: null
   */
```

Please ensure you are using the correct syntax for the client you are using.

Try:

```
const params = {
  TableName: TableName,
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#enablee": "enabled"},
  FilterExpression: "#enabled = :enabled",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":enabled": true
  },
};


const data = await ddbDocClient.send(new ScanCommand(params));
```

Comment: Sorry, am new to AWS and dynamoDb. What do you mean by mixing up clients? Could you please explain more on it?
```import { ScanInput } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';
```
this is the type, I am using .. the params need to be properly typed as I am using typescript too.

Comment: Please share your entire code.